# Restore RAW drive back to NTFS

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery, raw

Recently, I have tried to make backup of SSD of my laptop using Macrium Reflect 8 Portable Free edition. However, this process ended in error (which, unfortunatelly, I can't remember, my apologies) and after a reboot I have encountered an error. I am using Windows 8.1 64x bit.

So, after that apparent error, I have encountered disk damage (due to CHKDSK activation every time it boots). What actually bothers me, is that damaged disk is not SSD (which was backed up) but HDD. Apperently, I have **3 windows partitions** and Linux OS installed (which I don't care about and didn't even boot for long time) on that HHD drive. *Only **D:** drive is in working condition*, while partitions **E:** and **F:** aren't even displaying their size.

I tried using **CHKDSK** and **Disk Management**, but it doesn't work because the partitions are considered to be **RAW**. I cannot format thoser drives because *there is a lot of valuable data*, and neither I cannot recover files because my external doesn't have enough memory.

Is there any reliable software to cure my problem? I tried to research instructions on **TestDisk**, but I have no idea how to use it. Other software I can recall is **iBoysoft Data Recovery**, however, **70$** seems to be very high price for one-time use (without any guarantee, that it will help). I require some help, please.

Comment: This is a duplicate. [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device)